# what is the R code for splitting columns and adding a date

Tags: r

I have a input file like this

| Product | Days | SALES |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Google | MTWTFSASU | 28000 |
| Google | TFSASU | 10000 |

I need the data to split like this. The date here is a start_date value which I input from a txt file .
LEts consider start_date="01/01/2021". Then the first occurrence should have the date as "01/01/2021" for Monday and then the consecutive days based on the day(Monday-Sunday).

| Product | Days | SALES | NO_OF_DAYS | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Google | M | 4000 | 7 | 01/01/2021 |
| Google | T | 4000 | 7 | 01/02/2021 |
| Google | W | 4000 | 7 | 01/03/2021 |
| Google | T | 4000 | 7 | 01/04/2021 |
| Google | F | 4000 | 7 | 01/05/2021 |
| Google | SA | 4000 | 7 | 01/06/2021 |
| Google | SU | 4000 | 7 | 01/07/2021 |
| Apple | T | 2500 | 4 | 01/02/2021 |
| Apple | F | 2500 | 4 | 01/05/2021 |
| Apple | SA | 2500 | 4 | 01/06/2021 |
| Apple | SU | 2500 | 4 | 01/07/2021 |

Comment: For the Apple, should that te Thursday

Comment: The representation of Thursday in first case and second case are different? Is it like that?

Comment: Your input is different compared to output

Comment: How do you represent thursday in the dataset.  There is a conflict in first one `MTWTFSASU` vs `THFSASU`

Comment: Ya. I was expecting that. But the input file seems a little crazy. It has T for Tuesday and T for Thursday as well. So if the value is "MTW----" then the T is a Tuesday but if it is "--"---TFSaSu" or "---T----" then it is Thursday. I think the hyphens before the value denotes where is placed in the week. I hope this helps

Comment: We may have to replace Thursday present in the second one as TH and retain the tuesday value as T

Comment: Just for consistency, I created the data in my post as `MTWTHFSASU`

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create a key/value dataset that maps the 'Days' with the 'DATE' and after the `unnest`ing step do a join

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
keydat <- tibble(Days = c("M", "T", "W", "TH", "F", "SA", "SU"),
    DATE = format(seq(as.Date('2021-01-01'),
        length.out = length(Days), by = '1 day'), '%m/%d/%Y'))

df1 %>% 
   mutate(Days = str_extract_all(Days, "M|TH|W|T|F|SA|SU"),
       No_of_Days = lengths(Days),
       SALES = SALES/No_of_Days) %>% 
       unnest(c(Days)) %>%
       left_join(keydat)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 11 x 5
#   Product Days  SALES No_of_Days DATE      
#   <chr>   <chr> <dbl>      <int> <chr>     
# 1 Google  M      4000          7 01/01/2021
# 2 Google  T      4000          7 01/02/2021
# 3 Google  W      4000          7 01/03/2021
# 4 Google  TH     4000          7 01/04/2021
# 5 Google  F      4000          7 01/05/2021
# 6 Google  SA     4000          7 01/06/2021
# 7 Google  SU     4000          7 01/07/2021
# 8 Apple   TH     2500          4 01/04/2021
# 9 Apple   F      2500          4 01/05/2021
#10 Apple   SA     2500          4 01/06/2021
#11 Apple   SU     2500          4 01/07/2021
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Product = c("Google", "Apple"), Days = c("MTWTHFSASU", 
"THFSASU"), SALES = c(28000L, 10000L)), row.names = c(NA, -2L
), class = "data.frame")
```